# ¿Como ejecutar un contenedor de Docker de una maquina virtual Ubuntu Server para ser visualizado en Windows?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, redes, docker-compose

Tengo los siguientes contenedores
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comprendo que se esta ejecutando de forma local en la maquina virtual de Ubuntu
pero logro que se visualice en Windows.

Comment: Con qué hipervisor estas manejando la virtualización? virtualbox, vmware ...

Comment: Con VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes conocer es la ip de la maquina virtual, para eso entras en tu Ubuntu y desde un terminal tecleas **ifconfig**, una vez que tengas la ip abres una consola en Windows para comprobar que ambas maquinas se ven y tecleas **ping ip_tu_pc_con_Ubuntu**, si ambas maquinas se ven entonces desde tu pc de Windows deberias poder utilizar los servicios que tienes publicado en Ubuntu utilizando el puerto de cada servicio, por ejemplo, **ip_tu_pc_con_Ubuntu:7050**

Comment: Hola @fercho-jerez, por favor, comentanos si la respuesta te sirvio y si no entonces dinos para ver si podemos ayudarte de otra forma.